# How to list all of Magento 2's messages

Tags: magento-2.1, messages, notification

I've seen multiple types of messages on magento 2. Error messages, success messages and so on. How can I get the total number of messages that magento can provide? It should be sum of messages displayed on each and every scenario.

How can I get that exact amount?

Answer (score 2):

You can check all available messages in Magento, Check below file

```
vendor/magento/framework/Message/ManagerInterface.php
```

List of messages in Magento

> addMessage
>
> addMessages
>
> addError
>
> addWarning
>
> addNotice
>
> addSuccess
>
> addErrorMessage
>
> addWarningMessage
>
> addNoticeMessage
>
> addSuccessMessage
>
> addComplexErrorMessage
>
> addComplexWarningMessage
>
> addComplexNoticeMessage
>
> addComplexSuccessMessage
>
> addUniqueMessages
>
> addException
>
> addExceptionMessag

Answer (score 1):

**Using below code you can get the all current session messages**

```
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\Success;
use Magento\Framework\Message\Error;
use Magento\Framework\Message\Warning;
use Magento\Framework\Message\Notice;

class Message
{
/**
 * @var ManagerInterface
 */
private $messageInterface;

/**
 * Message constructor
 * @param ManagerInterface $messageInterface ManagerInterface
 */
public function __construct(
    ManagerInterface $messageInterface
) {
    $this->messageInterface = $messageInterface;
}//end __construct()

public function execute()
{
    $messages     = $this->messageInterface->getMessages(false);
    $messageArray = [];
    foreach ($messages->getItems() as $message) {
        if ($message instanceof Success) {
            $messageArray['success'][] = $message->getText();
        }
        if ($message instanceof Error) {
            $messageArray['error'][] = $message->getText();
        }
        if ($message instanceof Warning) {
            $messageArray['warning'][] = $message->getText();
        }
        if ($message instanceof Notice) {
            $messageArray['notice'][] = $message->getText();
        }
    }
    if (isset($messageArray['success'])) {
        $messageArray['success'] = array_unique($messageArray['success']);
    }
    if (isset($messageArray['error'])) {
        $messageArray['error'] = array_unique($messageArray['error']);
    }
    if (isset($messageArray['warning'])) {
        $messageArray['warning'] = array_unique($messageArray['warning']);
    }
    if (isset($messageArray['notice'])) {
        $messageArray['notice'] = array_unique($messageArray['notice']);
    }

    print_r($messageArray);
     }//end execute()
}//end class
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mostly we need below messages, that you can display for viewing purpose like this**

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$messageManager = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface');
$messageManager->addError('This is Error Message');
$messageManager->addSuccess('This is Success Message');
$messageManager->addNotice('This is Notice Message');
$messageManager->addWarning('This is Warning Message');
?>
```